# Saturation of penetration length using Lucas-Washburn equation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pressure, applied-mechanics, aerospace-engineering

The Washburn equation for capillary flow provides the following expression for the calculation of the penetration depth (or capillary rise):

$L \propto \sqrt(t)$

My question is when t goes to infinity, as per this equation, L goes to infinity. But don't we expect a equilibrium length, meaning there should a saturation behavior for this equation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The formulation assumes an infinite source of liquid with no internal inertia flowing into the pore. An analogy is to consider the development for the temperature penetration profile from an infinite heat source (i.e. a constant temperature source) into a semi-infinite solid.